# Cypress async issue

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have a situation in my test where I click a button and it makes an apollo graphQL call in my reactJS side.

```
          createProductCategory({
            variables: {
              restaurantID: props.restaurant.id,
              name: name
            }
          });
```

This is how it looks like in the ReactJS side. This **createProductCategory** method returns a **promise** which we wait for and continue with the rest of the code.

This works perfectly fine when I click on the button manually. I can see the graphQL call being made in the network tab and it works perfectly fine. However, if I try to get cypress to click on the button, I can see the button gets clicked, but the graphQL call never gets made. I just cannot understand why it doesn't work and what I am doing wrong.

Can someone please help me out with this. I tried putting wait statements everywhere but it just doesnt "wait" for the promise in the reactJS side to be resolved.

```
      cy.contains("Save")
        .click()
        .then(() => {
          cy.wait(2000)
        });

     cy.wait(2000)
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: can you compare the xhr request between manual and cypress clicking the button in chrome developer tool? From your statement it seems there is no xhr request when you use cypress?

Comment: The issue is that there is no XHR request made when cypress clicks it

Comment: What cypress version are you on? If not 3.5.0, and the button listens on `pointerdown` or some event like that, then it won't be triggered by `cy.click`.

Comment: You could have a wrapper (<a>) that handles onClick and your button doesn't do anything at all. Take a step back and make sure if the onClick handler which executes the graphQL call is triggered. To do that, just put console.log before the graphQL line.

Comment: The waits are not important because you're not testing anything afterwards. You need to be sure that your contains() is retrieving the right button, then be sure that the listener listens for click (no HammerJS, or other funny events)

Answer (score 1):

From what you are describing you should have code that surrounds the button click and waits for the graphql call to complete like so

```
cy.server()
cy.route('/graphql').as('graphql')
cy.get('buton').contains('abc').click()
cy.wait('@graphql')
```

More info: [alias waits](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Alias)